# How can I change the file private URL

Tags: 8

So I've uploaded a private file. It can be accessed like following:

`http://drupal8.dev/system/files/2016-12/README.txt`

How can I change how that file is accessed?

`http://drupal8.dev/files/README.txt`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a route in system.routing.yml:

```
system.private_file_download:
  path: '/system/files/{filepath}'
  defaults:
    _controller: 'Drupal\system\FileDownloadController::download'
  requirements:
    # Permissive regex to allow slashes in filepath see
    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/slash_in_parameter.html
    filepath: .+
    _access: 'TRUE'
```

You can change the path in a route subscriber.

Reference: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/altering-existing-routes-and-adding-new-routes-based-on-dynamic-ones

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand the question: To the best of my knowledge, you cannot. For a file in the private file system, the file URL must be rendered on a page in order to be accessed. Redirects and rewrites won't work.